# Accessibility Element is not focused while navigating via swipers but it's focusing while touching the elements

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, accessibility

I have created a custom control to create navigation pane in the application which has a content area and a sliding panel that slides out from the edge of the page in Xamarin.iOS using the UIView and I need to provide Accessibility support for the same. First, I created a view where I will add the elements in the content area and converted it to the native view in the iOS renderer. Then, I tried to navigate the elements that are added in **the content view via swipers but it is not moving but it is focusing while touching the elements**. I have set **isAccessibilityElement to false to make the content view focusable**. I need to make the elements accessible while swiping. Can anyone help? and thanks in Advance. Please find the codes below:

Simple sample code snippet:

```
 <drawer:CustomControl  x:Name="drawer">
    <drawer:CustomControl.ContentView>
        <StackLayout Margin="0,100,0,0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Button Text="Button" />
            <Label Text="ContentView"/>
            <Button  Text=" Button2"/>
            <Label Text="ContentView2"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </drawer:CustomControl.ContentView>
</drawer:CustomControl>
```

Native code snippet:

```
public class SimpleControl : UIView
{
    UIView contentView;
    public UIView ContentView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contentView;
        }

        set
        {
            this.contentView = value;
            this.Add(this.contentView);
        }
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        this.IsAccessibilityElement = false;
    }
}
```

Xamarin.Forms

```
public class CustomControl: View
{
    public View ContentView
    {
        get { return (View)GetValue(ContentViewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentViewProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ContentViewProperty =  BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ContentView), typeof(View), typeof(CustomControl), null, BindingMode.Default);


    public CustomControl()
    {
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        if (Double.IsNaN(widthConstraint) || Double.IsNaN(heightConstraint)
            || Double.IsInfinity(widthConstraint) || Double.IsInfinity(heightConstraint))
        {
            SizeRequest size = base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
            widthConstraint = size.Request.Width;
            heightConstraint = size.Request.Height;

        }
        return new SizeRequest(new Size(widthConstraint, heightConstraint));
    }
}
```

iOS Renderer:

```
public class CustomControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomControl, Native>
{
    public CustomControlRenderer()
    {
    }

     Native nativeDrawer;
     CustomControl drawer;
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomControl> e)
     {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            drawer = e.NewElement;

            if (nativeDrawer == null)
            {
                nativeDrawer = new Native ();
                UIView v = new UIView();
                v.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 600, 1500);
                nativeDrawer.ContentView = CustomControlRenderer.ConvertFormsToNativeView(drawer.ContentView, v.Frame, drawer, drawer.BindingContext);
            }

            SetNativeControl(nativeDrawer);
        }
     }


    internal static UIView ConvertFormsToNativeView(Xamarin.Forms.View view, CGRect size, CustomControl drawer, object bindingContext)
    {
        if (view == null)
            return null;
        if (view.BindingContext == null)
        {
            if (bindingContext != null)
            {
                view.BindingContext = bindingContext;
            }
            else
            {
                view.BindingContext = drawer.BindingContext;
            }
        }

        return GetNativeView(view, drawer, view.BindingContext, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is an expected result  . We need to swipe the screen with three fingers in Accessibility mode if we want to scroll the control(like UItableView) or navigate to another page .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks for replying. I'm not able to move to the next element via swiping.

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side .It seems there is no issue in your codes .